# How to Make Android App Compatible for all 6735 Android Devices in Android Studio

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout, android-support-library

This question is already asked by someone but that not feasible for now. My app is using minSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 30 and crashing on Oppo and Nokia 6

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  First off look at your minSdkVersion-  any device below that version won't work.  So to make it work on everything you'd need to have minSdkVersion 1 (you might get away with 3 as that's the lowest commercially available device I know of).  Then you'd need to only use functionality available on all those versions, so you would basically have to program to the 2010 version of Android.  And even then there will be incompatibilities.

Instead, you decide on a version of Android that will support a large enough percent of the market in your target geographical area.  You program to that.  And then if you find specific incompatibilities you fix those.

As for the 2 versions you specified-  Nokia6 can be as low as SDK version 25.  So that may be why it isn't working.  Oppo is a brand so you have to be much more specific there.